# KKT condition for linear equality

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

I'm a bit confused regarding the stationarity condition of the KKT conditions.

Consider: $$\max_{x_1, x_2, 2x_1 + x_2 = 3} x_1 + x_2$$

From the stationarity condition, we know that there has to exist $\lambda$ s.t:

$$1 - 2\lambda = 0 \land 1 - \lambda = 0$$

which cannot hold. I must be missing something obvious. Thanks.

Comment: To apply the KKT you need to know first that there is an extremum.

Answer (score 1):

Define:

$$
f(x) = x_1 + x_2
$$

$$
g(x) = 2 x_1 + x_2 - 3
$$

The constrained optimization problem is:

$$
\mbox{Maximize}  \ f(x)
$$
$$
\mbox{Subject to} \ \ g(x) = 0
$$

Define the Lagrangian Function
$$
L(x) = f(x) - \lambda g(x) = x_1 + x_2 - \lambda ( 2 x_1 + x_2 - 3 )
$$

Necessary conditions for optimality are:
$$
(1) \ \ {\partial L \over \partial x_1} = 0
$$
$$
(2) \ \ {\partial L \over \partial x_2} = 0
$$
$$
(3) \ \ {\partial L \over \partial \lambda} = 0
$$

Simplifying, we get
$$
(1) \ \ 1 - 2 \lambda = 0 \ \ \mbox{or} \ \ \lambda = {1 \over 2}
$$
$$
(2) \ \ 1 - \lambda = 0 \ \ \mbox{or} \ \ \lambda = 1
$$
$$
(3) \ \ 2 x_1 + x_2 - 3 = 0
$$

Since (1) and (2) contradict each other, the necessary condition for optimality is not satisfied.

This means that the constrained optimization problem does not have a maximum value.

This is also clear geometrically.

We are trying to maximize  the function
$$
f(x) = x_1 + x_2
$$
along the straight line
$$
2 x_1 + x_2 = 3
$$

We notice that the sum of the coordinates of the points lying on the straight line $$
2 x_1 + x_2 =  3
$$
can increase in its value arbitrarily.
[[image: Plot of the straight line <span class=]$2 x_1 + x_2 = 3$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPl5L.jpg)